# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

Here is what I have done and understood so far:

My Webpage run from `http://localhost:80`, I need to access some API calls at `http://localhost:8080`.

I require to enable CORS, as its a POST and Content-Type is application/json.

So I implemented OPTIONS method on the server and set all the required headers.

Here is the OPTIONS request which the browser makes
Request :

```
OPTIONS /0/VERIFICATION HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-key, x-signature, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/jquery.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Key,X-Signature,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Key,X-Signature,Content-Type
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
```

So I can see all the appropriate headers being set and all looks good until the actual request is made which fails with the following error

Error in Chrome Console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/0/VERIFICATION. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my javascript code which is making the actual request

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
 }

function makeCorsRequest() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/0/VERIFICATION";
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var text = xhr.responseText;
        alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Signature", "abcd");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Key", "key1");
    xhr.send("{json data}");
 }
```

I am using Chrome browser to test the above scenario, my server is a netty based server and html pages are being served via apache.

Update added .htaccess based on the comment below and still the same error.

```
curl -v 'http://localhost/jquery.html'
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /jquery.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.36.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 18 Jul 2014 07:03:22 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.9 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.9
< Last-Modified: Sun, 30 Mar 2014 06:31:53 GMT
< ETag: "3af-4f5cd17308840"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 943
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, x-http-method-override, content-    type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Content-Type: text/html
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the headers when you serve the html pages, too. `.htaccess` for Apache:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, x-http-method-override, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the browser, curl or wireshark could tell what was going wrong. The problem was very was lame, I did the following on the server :

```
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "X-Key,X-Signature,Content-Type");
```

The **correct** way is :

```
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS, "X-Key");
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS, "X-Signature");
response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS, "Content-Type");
```